# Does $g(n)$ approach $\frac{n}{2} - \pi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $m = 2n$. Let $g(m)$ represent the number of odd composites (no duplicates) less than $n$ such that there exist at least one $p < n$ with $m$ congruent to any of the odd composites mod $p$. Does $g(m)$ become arbitrarily close to $\frac{n}{2} - \pi(n)$, and why or why not? By arbitrarily close, I mean that $\frac{n}{2} - \pi(n) - g(m)<3.$ The number $3$ plays an important role in my research.

I think the answer is yes--as $n$ becomes large, the number of odd composites that satisfy the above condition become arbitrarily close to the number of odd composites less than $n$, but I have no proof for this (and am looking for one in your answer). I know $g(m) \le \frac{n}{2} -\pi(n)$ for all $n$.

Selected values of $g(m)$ are as follows:

$\quad g(18)=1, g(20)=0, g(34)=1, g(36)=2,g(42)=3,g(50)=2$

Comment: What did you really mean ? What means arbitrary close ?  Let $\pi_{a,q}(x) = \sum_{p \text{ prime} \equiv a \bmod q} 1$. If $gcd(a,q)=1$ then the Dirichlet theorem in arithmetic progressions says $\pi_{a,q}(x) = \frac{\pi(x)}{\phi(q)} + o(\frac{x}{\log^k x})$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the pointer. I've added what I mean by arbitrarily close. As far as your reference to Dirichlet's theorem; I am not allowed to assume $gcd(a, q) = 1$ and also I'm looking for odd composites, not primes, that fit my condition.

Comment: @LinusRastegar Please edit your question to make it more clear.  Since $g(n)$ is not parametrized by $p$, does "that are congruent to $n$ mod $p$ where $p$ is any prime less than $n$" really mean "such that there exists a prime $p<n$ with..." ?

Comment: Have you tried to write a code to test for the first $n=10000$ for example?

Comment: We can partition the set of the first $2n$ natural numbers as
$$2n=|\{1\}| + |\{k \mid k \leq 2n, k\text{-even} \}| + |\{p \mid p <2n, p \text{ - odd prime} \}| + |\{t \mid t < 2n, t\text{ - odd and composite} \}|=1+n+\pi(2n)-1+g(n)$$
then $$g(n)=n-\pi(2n)$$
Simply because $|t-n|<n \Rightarrow \exists p\text{-prime}, p<n: t \equiv n \pmod{p}$, simply because $|t-n|$ is either prime ($<n$) or composite. Is that roughly what are you looking for?

Comment: @ErickWong I did my best to revise the question using your word choice but I may have made it a little more complicated to understand (I've edited the question now). Thanks for the suggestion anyhow.

Comment: @rtybase Yes, that's the sort of proof/reasoning I'm looking for, though I take issue with the last step. According to your reasoning, $g(n)$ also represents the amount of composites up to $2n$ which is not correct. I've edited the question a little now, but your reasoning could still be applied--$g(32)$ is a counterexample nonetheless.

Comment: Indeed it looks more complicated (or confusing). I'd suggest adding an example to your question, whoever is quicker will update the question accordingly ...

Comment: @rtybase I've added example values for $g(n)$--is that what you meant?

Comment: Almost, how did you get $g(18)=1$? There are two odd composites $<18$, $9$ and $15$. And $9 \equiv 36 \pmod{3}$, $15 \equiv 36 \pmod{7}$, both $3$ and $7$ are $< 18$. Following the question, $g(18)=2$? Did you mean "square free" by "no duplicates"?

Comment: @rtybase I made a mistake when transferring results from my program to the question: I've updated the question by updating the function definition with a different argument.

Comment: please give full explanation on the examples you gave, $g(42)=3$ why ?